# Launching Process On Remote Server With SSH - Don't Want Process In Background

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have written the following script:

```
#Other code above ...

read -p "Enter the full hostname for the Component we need to degrade: " input

#I move the file that I want to execute across to the specified host
rsync -azvh ~/RTL_COUNTER.sh username@$input:/home/username/

#I then want to run this process, and only have my shell script move forward when it completes (it contains a loop)
#Note that I have to sudo up here as the shell script being executed queries the JMX

ssh -t username@$input "sudo su - SUPERUSE;/home/username/RTL_COUNTER.sh" 

#Other code follows ...
```

This works, however I need the execution of `/users/username/RTL_COUNTER.sh` to not run in the background - this script should not proceed until that script is finished.

Is there any way to do this?

NOTE: RTL_COUNTER.sh looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

test="$(echo "get -s -b com.service.oms:name=XXXXXTransactionMonitor RunningTasks" | /usr/local/latest/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx256m -jar /usr/local/bin/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar --url localhost:XXXXXXXXX -urole -p ` grep controlRole PW HERE | awk '{print $2}' ` -n -v silent | wc -l)"
echo "${test}"

function check {
        test="$(echo "get -s -b com.service.oms:name=XXXXXTransactionMonitor RunningTasks" | /usr/local/latest/bin/java -Xms256m -Xmx256m -jar /usr/local/bin/jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar --url localhost:xxxxx -u controlRole -p ` grep role XXXXXX | awk '{print $2}' ` -n -v silent | wc -l)"
                if [ ${test} != "1" ]
                then
                        echo  ${test}
                        check
                else
                        echo "###########################"
                        echo "#SAFE TO DELETE - NO TASKS#"
                        echo "###########################"
                fi
                }
check
```

Comment: You say you want to run the script in the background, but in the next sentence you say "this script should not proceed until that script is finished". This is confusing.

Comment: I don't want it to run in the background, where is this error and I will fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the "don't".

Comment: Are you knowingly calling `check` recursively, or is that an error?

Comment: It's being called recursively on purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a slight syntax error...

```
sudo su - SUPERUSE;/home/username/RTL_COUNTER.sh
```

means...

```
# su to a SUPERUSE + exit, because of the ";"
# execute the script as whatever use ssh'ed into machine
/home/username/RTL_COUNTER.sh
```

Try this instead...

```
sudo su - SUPERUSE -- /home/username/RTL_COUNTER.sh
```

Note the removed ";" character.

Comment: hmm, now getting `-bash: /home/username/RTL_COUNTER.sh: Permission denied`

Comment: Changed to `sudo su - SUPERUSE -- /home/username/RTL_COUNTER.sh` to  `sudo /home/username/RTL_COUNTER.sh` and it works! Change you're answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Accepted answer - for future readers please note my comment.